# Removing created named pipes

Tags: c, pipe

I have this code that synchronises a process using named pipes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>



int main()
{   int fd,val,i,fd2;
    pid_t c1;
    char *myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";
    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);
    char *myfifo2 = "/tmp/myfifo2";
    mkfifo(myfifo2, 0666);
    c1=fork();


    if(c1==0){

      for( i=0;i<6;i++){
      if(i==1||i==3||i==5){
         fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
         read(fd, &val, sizeof(val));
         close(fd);
         for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
             printf("critical:2\n");
             }
         fd2 = open(myfifo2, O_WRONLY);
         write(fd2, &val, sizeof(val));
                    }
      if(i==0||i==2||i==4){
             for(i=0;i<7;i++){
             printf("non critical:2\n");
             }
             }}}


    if(c1>0){
        val=10;
        fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
        write(fd, &val, sizeof(val));
        fd2 = open(myfifo2, O_RDONLY);
        read(fd2, &val, sizeof(val));
        close(fd2);

    wait(0);

    }
}
```

Normally father's code is inside a loop so the child does not get stuck.What i noticed is that after concecutive runs of this program the result is unreasonable(not just wrong).I think this happens because pipes created do not die between program runs so the result is upredictable.Close pipe seems to block the pipe until it is opened by someone but not destroy it.So,how can i destroy these pipes at the end of the program so that running it again i will not cause that problem?

Comment: [`unlink`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/unlink)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca So in this case it would be ulink(*myfifo); and unlink(*myfifo2); right?

Comment: Why are you dereferencing your string variables? `unlink()` doesn't take a char.

Comment: Named pipes have *filesystem* persistence (which is why you must unlink them to get rid of them).  If you want something limited to a parent process and its descendants communicating among themselves, then a standard pipe, as obtained via [`pipe`(**2**)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html), is a more appropriate choice than a named pipe.

Comment: @JohnBollinger i need the read() of the pipe to work as a wait and i need that to happen multiple times.Can i somehow close and reopen an unamed pipe to use it's read as a wait multiple times?

Comment: @leonardoystapor, `read()`ing from *any* pipe will block until there are data available (or the write end is no longer open anywhere).  This does not depend  on closing and opening, except as already mentioned.  For a named pipe, *opening* the pipe that will block until the other end is also opened, but I see no reason why you would need (or want) to rely on that for your purposes.